# Splitting channel list in irssi?

Tags: irssi

Alright, I have been reading the documentation I don't know if I missed it but how can I put the channel list (the people in the channel) to the right side like this theme here

[image: theme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for nicklist.pl on http://scripts.irssi.org/.

EDIT: this is some help about its use: http://wouter.coekaerts.be/site/irssi/nicklist

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 'enzotibs' correct answer some more detailed information:

1. Download the nicklist.pl script [directly here](http://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/nicklist.pl), or use [scripts.irssi.org](http://scripts.irssi.org/).
2. Now you can put the downloaded `nicklist.pl` script into `~/.irssi/scripts/`.
3. Make an alias of nicklist.pl and put the alias into `~/.irssi/scripts/autorun`, then change its name to nicklist.pl again.
4. Now open a terminal window and download [screen](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server):

   > sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get install screen
5. Now open another terminal window and type:

   > screen irssi
   >   /nicklist screen
   >   /server servername.blah
   >   /join #channel
6. Now you should have exactly what you asked for!

**Some more information on how to handle** `.pl` **scripts in irssi**:

**Q:** How do I run scripts?
**A:** Put them into `~/.irssi/scripts/` and in irssi do `/script load script.pl`. There is a default alias for `/script load` to `/run` in newer versions of irssi.

**Q:** How do I rerun scripts?
**A:** Just do `/script load script.pl`

**Q:** How do I unload scripts?
**A:** Just do `/script unload script.pl`

**Q:** How do I run scripts automatically at startup?
**A:** Put them into `~/.irssi/scripts/autorun/` directory. Or better would be if you placed them in `~/.irssi/scripts/` and created symlinks to autorun directory (eg. `cd ~/.irssi/scripts/autorun/ ; ln -s ../script.pl`)

**Q:** Is there an easy way of managing script?
**A:** Try scriptassist.pl, it can update and manage your scripts as well as install new ones and search the database.